# WCF - Cannot create abstract class

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, soap, abstract

I'm writing a WCF webservice and passing in a complex type as a parameter of the method. The complex type looks like this:

```
 [DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class MyRequest 
{
    [DataMember()]
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public bool IsRollback { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public OrderType OrderType { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public ICustomerId CustomerId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    [DataMember()]
    public AnotherComplexType PurchaseInfo { get; set; }
```

The webservice method looks like this:

```
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CustomerIdByName))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(CustomerIdByAccount))]
public OrderResult Execute(MyRequest order) {
}
```

The Interface looks like this:

```
[KnownType(typeof(CustomerIdByAccount))]    
[KnownType(typeof(CustomerIdByName))]
public interface ICustomerId{

string GetId();
}
```

When I make a request using the SOAP end point, everything works just great. But when passing the request to the REST end point, I get the serialization error.

This is the request I'm using

```
<MyRequest>
<CustomerId>
<AccountId>59251</AccountId>
</CustomerId>
<IsRollback>false</IsRollback>
<OrderId>0</OrderId>
<OrderType>OrderSubscription</OrderType>
<PurchaseInfo>
<ObjectId>196521</ObjectId>
</PurchaseInfo>
<TransactionId>ABC123</TransactionGuid>
</MyRequest>
```

Since I had been stuck at this point for too long, I then changed the ICustomerId member to be an abstract class that implements ICustomerId. Again the SOAP end point works fine but sending the request to the rest end point I get an error that states "Cannot create abstract class"

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Is this failing because the interface is nested in the complex type and not a direct parameter of the webservice method? I've used webservices that receive interfaces as parameter and with the KnownType decorators they work just fine. Same question applies to the abstract class, is this not working because the abstract class is nested within a member of the MyRequest complex type?

This is the error message I am getting:

> Element CustomerId from namespace cannot have child contents to be deserialized as an object. Please use XmlNode[] to deserialize this pattern of XML

Comment: `OrderResult Execute(OrderRequest order)` does not return anything.  Also, does `MyRequest` implement everything that `IMyRequest` supports?

Comment: is there a datacontract/datamember on children ?

Comment: I have a concrete class that extends the abstract CustomerId. It's called "CustomerIdByAccount" and it has a public property "AccountId". I updated the question with a sample XML I'm using for the request

Comment: `OrderResult` and `AnotherComplexType` also need to be DataContracts.

Comment: They are data contracts. CustomerId is a data member of type ICustomerId, the deserializer doesn't seem to understand that CustomerIdByAccount is a known type that implements that interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried decorating your interface as a RESTful method?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyRequest
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(
       UriTemplate = "Requests/GetID",
       Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    string GetId(MyRequest myRequest);
...
```

Also:

- make sure that the [DataMember] properties match your request payload. Everything that gets passed in your XML request payload must be caught by the serializer in the service. I recommend keeping the naming the same, but you can map it using [DataMember(name="MyProperty")]. Also, your [DataContract] must be mapped to match the name of the parent node of your XML payload like [DataContract(Name="MyRequest")] but only if the class is named differently than the xml node. Do this, and it will deserialize your xml into the server side object/dto
- The error you're getting sounds like it's complaining about the complex type inside of your DataContract. Your complex type needs to be decorated for serialization the same as your MyRequest type.
- Also ensure your REST endpoint is bound to webHttpBinding

Comment: Sorry, the interface is not the service's interface. I have another one for that where I have put the WebInvoke annotations, etc. This interface is just for the customer identifier, we only use account id right now now to identify a customer but in the future it could be equipment serial number, address, etc... That's why I wanted to use the interface rather than a fixed type for this data member, I can continue to add more types as we grow. The problem is that even though I hit the deserializer with the known types for that interface, still it does not know how to deserialize it.

Comment: Fair enough, but I still see that your payload does not match the dto object. And you have an interface as a member that only exposes a method. Methods don't serialize. So I'm not sure how the compiler would know which implementation to use as that implementation will not survive the serialization/deserialization process.

Comment: Well, I mean there are ways around that, but I'd ask yourself if you really need to go through that pain or rethink. Generally speaking, you're not going to want to deal with the pain of passing full implementations of objects through the WCF service. IMO, deal with pure xml on the client side and then just manage that in the service.

Comment: I didn't know methods don't serialize. My first attempt was to make a property "Id" in the interface and CustomerIdByAccount would have a private member to hold the account id but a "get" on the "Id" property would return this same private value in string format. Didn't work... Same error. I also tried making a CustomerId abstract class that implements the ICustomerId interface. Then CustomerIdByAccount extends the abstract class. I got an error stating "Cannot create an abstract class". Can you think of another alternative? and thanks a bunch for you help!

Comment: I think you can still do it using an interface the same way that you're doing it, now that I think about it. But it still feels like a design smell. Otherwise, I think the real problem is that your payload doesn't match your business object. Hmmm... is your body style wrapped? Also, try adding knowntypeof(CustomerId). Bear in mind that inheritance doesn't persist through serialization, thats why you have to spell out the inheritance through knowntypeof. If that doesn't work, try ditching the interface and using a base type.

Comment: Right now, the server side object is expecting an ICustomerId and is getting a CustomerId instead and at this stage, it doesn't realize that CustomerId "is a" ICustomerId

Comment: I gave up on trying to serialize this complex type with an interface as data member. I think you can add hints for direct arguments of the service but when the interface is nested within another complex type it doesn't seem to work as I would expect. I changed the API interface and I create the objects on the server side. The xml is completely flat now. Thanks a lot for your recommendations!